# Reflection .NET Core Create Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, .net-core

I'm trying to create a lambda expression (using Reflection) which looks like this

```
IServiceProvider provider => provider.GetService<TDbContext>()
```

Or, to be more specific, as `GetService` is an extension method :

```
provider => ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService<TDbContext>(provider)
```

This is my code:

```
 var methodInfo = typeof(ServiceProviderServiceExtensions).
                GetTypeInfo().
                GetMethod("GetService").
                MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDbContext));

        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(methodInfo, Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider), "provider")),
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider), "provider")
            );

var compiledLambdaExpression = lambdaExpression.Compile();
```

I'm getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: variable 'provider' of type
>   'System.IServiceProvider' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've created two different parameters with the same name.  You should call `Expression.Parameter` just once and save the result and then use it:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(ServiceProviderServiceExtensions).
            GetTypeInfo().
            GetMethod("GetService").
            MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDbContext));

var providerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider), "provider");

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call( methodInfo, providerParam ),
        providerParam
        );

var compiledLambdaExpression = lambdaExpression.Compile();
```